# conversão de numeros indo-arabicos para numeros romanos java

Tags: java

Boa tarde, Estou com uma certa dificuldade na programação de um conversor para numeros romanos, consegui separar as casas em milhar, centena, dezena e unidade da seguinte forma

```
 if(numericos==1000){

      while(numericos<=milhar){
      milhar = 1;

      }
     v[0]=milhar;
  }

  if(numericos>100){

      while(centenas<=numericos){
      centenas = centenas + 100;

      }
  centenas= centenas/100-1;
  numericos= numericos%100;
  v[1]=centenas;
  } 


  if(numericos>10){

      while(dezenas<=numericos){
      dezenas = dezenas + 10;
      numericos=numericos%10;
      }
     dezenas = dezenas/10-1;
     v[2]=dezenas;
  }
  if(numericos>1){

      while(unidades<=numericos){
      unidades = unidades + 1;
      }
       unidades = unidades - 1;
       v[3]=unidades;
  }
```

mas nao consigo pensar em uma logica de conversão sem meter trocentos ifs no codigo
alguem pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12967896) tem vários algoritmos diferentes :-)

Answer (score -1):

Eu costumo usar muito essas continhas para separar as unidades, dezenas, centenas, etc.

```
    int inteiro = 1239;
    int unidade = inteiro % 1000 % 100 % 10;
    int dezena = inteiro % 1000 % 100 / 10;
    int centena = inteiro % 1000 / 100;
    int milhar = inteiro / 1000;

    System.out.println(unidade);
    System.out.println(dezena);
    System.out.println(centena);
    System.out.println(milhar);

    //saída:
    //9
    //3
    //2
    //1
```